# How to log SOAP envelope from C# web service call?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

Is there any way to get the SOAP envelope generated by .NET when calling a web service through a C# proxy class? I'm looking to get the SOAP envelope with all of the parameters defined in .NET, not a generic, blank SOAP envelope like SoapUI creates.

Comment: You want to display it or simply check the envelop when developing? If it is just checking what the envelop looks like, you can use SOAPUI program. It will show the envelop for a specified method on a webService. You an then test it, with some values (the ones you put in your c# code for example).

Comment: I've already got the web service implemented on the C# end of things. I would like to generate a SOAP envelope from that C# implementation, if possible.

Comment: Are you using a Service Reference or a Web Reference? It's very easy to do with a service reference.

Comment: Web reference, unfortunately.

Comment: So, why not switch to a service reference? A web reference uses the legacy ASMX technology, which should not be used for new development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually just use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to intercept the SOAP envelope. You need to specify the local Fiddler proxy (default localhost:8888) on the webservice class for that to work.

```
ws.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("localhost", 8888);
```